# Confusion regarding map and linked hashmap

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap

I have this confusion in my mind regarding `LinkedHashMap`. 
In `Set` we do not have any key value pair, so when we try to print the set element, we will not get the order preserved for printing element as we have inserted, means order is not preserved, but when we are using `LinkedHashSet`, this will assure that order will be preserved, as we have inserted the element in linked hash set, while printing we will get the same order. This make sense.

But in case of `Map`, we print the values using key only, so what is the logic in saying that `LinkedHashMap` preserves order? We're supposed to print the values using key, so wherever the key-value pair is, the key will print its value. It has to go to map and search for that key and finally print its value.

I hope you will be able to get my question..

Comment: you can also iterate map.

Comment: internally set is wrapped in Map. have a look at code of HashSet and LinkedHashSet

Answer (score 3):

When you iterate map it will manage your order in linked Hash Map.

It is not like that you always get values using key only. you need to get all elements from the Map and you may not aware about it. for example -  **creating Select Drop down using map**.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> so what is the logic in saying that linked hash map preserve order

`LinkedHashMap` preserves (by default) the order in which the keys were first inserted to the Map. You can iterate over the keys using `keySet` or over the entries using `entrySet` in order to get the keys/entries in this order.

Comment: Map<Integer,String> m = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    
  m.put(1, "1");
  m.put(2, "2");
  m.put(3, "3");
  m.put(4, "4");
  m.put(5, "5");
  m.put(6, "6");
  m.put(7, "7");
  m.put(8, "8");
  m.put(9, "9");
  m.put(10,"10");
  m.put(11,"11");
  m.put(12,"12");
  m.put(13,"13");
  m.put(14,"14");
  m.put(15,"15");
  m.put(16,"16");
  m.put(17,"17");
  m.put(18,"18"); 

    
  for(Integer i:m.keySet()){
   System.out.print(" "+m.get(i));
  }

Comment: i always get the output 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 16 18
so, what is different in the order of preserving in linked hash map

Comment: if i would have used linked hash map, i would have got same output

Comment: @Max For these specific keys you get the same order. Change the first entry to `m.put(10000, "1")` and you'll get a different order.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can access the values of map without using keys, you can use values method.and all depends on the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the methods already mentioned, you can also use [`map.forEach()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) to iterate across your map entries in insertion order.